# Use an object as an anchor and show gif around it

Tags: anchor, object-detection, arkit

How I can detect objects and use these objects as anchors in an AR application? How I can show a gif around any particular detected object?

- Platform: ARkit/ Realitykit

Comment: Any research you could share with us? [ask]